# Access simple-prefs from xul window

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to access the simple-prefs module from a XUL settings dialog. My code looks as follows.

```js
var WINDOW = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowWatcher);
var mainWindow = MEDIATOR.getMostRecentWindow(null);

var pref = require("simple-prefs");
var win = WINDOW.openWindow(mainWindow, "chrome://myextension/content/settings.xul", "aboutMyExtension", "chrome,centerscreen,modal,dependant,dialog", pref);
```

As shown above, i give the simple prefs reference as an argument to the xul window.
In the xul page, I try the following to get the simple-prefs reference.

```xml
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://global/content/XPCNativeWrapper.js"/>
... 
XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(window.arguments[0])
```

`window.arguments[0]` is a `[xpconnect wrapped nsISupports]`, but the unwrap() returns a `[xpconnect wrapped nsISupports]` instead of actually unwrapping it.

So, how do I access the simple-prefs module from the xul dialog?

Comment: You don't have an event=passing channel back and forth between the addon code and the window, so even if you pass the values initially into the window ( as an array or hash ), you will still have problems reacting to pref changes. Dunno, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the loader from a script tag within your XUL window.

Like this:

```
<script type='application/javascript' src='resource://gre/modules/toolkit/loader.js'></script>
```

Then you could just `require('simple-prefs')` in your XUL window instead of trying to pass it over.

See more about the loader in the sdk low-level docs:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/toolkit/loader.html